# $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f = 0$ a.e. on $[0, 1]$ and range $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, functions

How do I construct $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f = 0$ almost everywhere on $[0, 1]$ and range $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: You want $f([0,1])=\Bbb R$?

Comment: Define $f(x)=0$ for $x$ outside the cantor set.  Then since the cantor set is uncountable you can find a 1-1 correspondence between it and $\Bbb R$.  Maybe something like that?

Comment: @GregoryGrant: Since he uses the words "almost everywhere", I suspect that $f$ should be measurable. Is your bijective correspondence measurable?

Comment: @AlexM. The function given by Gregory is measurable, because the Lebesgue measure is complete in the sense that, if $A\subseteq B$ and $\mu(B)=0$, then $A$ is measurable.

Comment: @ÁngelValencia Thank you!

Comment: @GregoryGrant uncountable need not imply the cardinality of the reals unless you accept the continuum hypothesis. Fortunately we know that the Cantor set has the cardinality of the reals already.

Answer (score 1):

The Cantor set $C$ has the same cardinal as $R\backslash \{0\}$ and is Lebesgue-null. So let $f:C\to R\backslash \{0\}$ be a surjection, and extend $f$ to the domain $[0,1]$ by letting $f(x)=0$ for $x\in [0,1]\backslash C.$

Comment: You don't really have to take $0$ off.

Comment: Funny.You're right.................